# Use LWC from managed package in custom community theme layout

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, managed-package, aura

I have built a custom theme for a community and am trying to use the Salesforce Labs cookieConsent component in my footer by referencing it with `<c:cookieConsent></c:cookieConsent>`. This https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000G11jcUAB

Is it possible to reference a Lightning Web Component from a managed package in a custom Aura component that implements `forceCommunity:themeLayout`

Comment: When referencing the component from the managed package, replace `c:name` with `namespace:name` where *namespace* is that of the managed package containing the component.

Comment: This worked. Thanks Phil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When referencing the component from the managed package, replace `c:name` with `namespace:name` where `namespace` is that of the managed package containing the component.